# Pickle loads variables.. out of order?

Tags: python, discord.py, pickle

i am working on a discord bot, and i am making heavy use of the pickle system so as to not lose variables between resets. it all has worked so far but i realized as i add more variables i would need to revamp my saving and loading system. so i decided to make the variables save when they are assigned to, as opposed to the original system which was saving them all when i ran a command.

old system:

```
try:
        if message.content == '>savevalues':
            await message.channel.send("""notice of revamping to not confuse users. this can be disregarded.""")
            servername = message.guild.name
            with open(f"{servername}.txt", 'wb') as f: #using variable as filename adds multi server compatibility and works fine.
                pickle.dump([variable1, variable2, variable3], f)
            f.close()
            await message.channel.send("Saved.")
    except NameError:
        try:
            await message.channel.send(f"variable1 is set, and it's value is {variable1}.")
        except:
            await message.channel.send("Alert: variable1 is not set, and is required. please set it to continue.")
            return
        try:
            await message.channel.send(f"variable2 is set, and it's value is {variable2}.")
        except:
            await message.channel.send("Alert: variable2 is not set, and is required. please set it to continue.")
            return
        try:
            await message.channel.send(f"variable3 is set and its value is {variable3}.")
        except:
            await message.channel.send("""Warning: variable3 is not set. it has a default value, \
but it is strongly recommended that you set it to avoid errors. the process will continue.""")
            with open(f"{servername}.txt", 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump([variable1, variable2], f)
            f.close()
            await message.channel.send("Saved.")
```

as you can see, it's big, and if not all of them are set i have to check them all just to make sure there are no errors. the new system negates that, as they are saved to file upon assignment, so they can be loaded independently.

```
if message.content == '>savev1':
    servername = message.guild.name
    placeholder = message.content
    variable1 = placeholder.replace('>savev1 ', '')
    with open(f'{servername}.txt', 'ab') as f:
        pickle.dump(variable1, f)
    f.close()
```

repeat for every variable.

this works fine, and if i set them in the same order as they are loaded it works just fine, but if i did

```
>setv2 1
>setv3 2
>setv1 3
```

and loaded them in the order

```
v1 > v2 > v3
```

i would get

```
variable1 = 1
variable2 = 2
variable3 = 3
```

this is not user friendly at all, and it makes no sense to me as i told pickle to save variable 3 as 1, but it saves 1 to the first variable loaded instead of the variable i saved it to? i looked but i can't find an answer.

also i know i'm not using rewrite, for some reason it doesnt work.

Comment: why to keep in separated variabeles. Keep it as list or dictionary, and save always full list/dict, and read always full list/dict.

Comment: pickle doesn't care what variables you use. It keeps only values

Comment: i implemented an entirely new system using lists. if this question has no answer and is to be closed then so be it. thanks @furas